# "The type name `Granite.Widgets.Avatar' could not be found" error building pantheon-mail

Tags: pantheon-mail

Installed dependencies like so:

sudo apt-get install cmake libvala-0.30-dev valac-0.30 libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libgranite-dev libcanberra-dev
libsqlite3-dev libgmime-2.6-dev libsecret-1-dev libgcr-3-dev libgirepository1.0-dev valadoc

Then tried to build the new pantheon-mail but getting stuck at this error

[ 76%] Generating .pantheon-mail.stamp
/usr/local/src/pantheon-mail/src/client/conversation-viewer/ConversationWidget.vala:98.13-98.34: error: The type name `Granite.Widgets.Avatar' could not be found
    private Granite.Widgets.Avatar avatar;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make[2]: *** [src/.pantheon-mail.stamp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pantheon-mail.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Not sure how to proceed, any build tips appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to build from tar.gz?

Comment: No building from latest version obtained via command: 'bzr branch lp:pantheon-mail'

Comment: Over freya 0.3?

Comment: Correct. elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (32-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build **pantheon-mail** with dependencies on **libgranite** over Freya 0.3.

This library version don't support "*Granite.Widgets.Avatar*", which it's incluided in **libgranite** for 0.4. You must upgrade it to this version before build **pantheon-mail**

More info:  [Granite on Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/granite)

You need to update the following libraries in order to satisfy all **pantheon-mail** dependencies:

- *libcairo2* (>= 1.2.4)
- *libgee-0.8-2* (>= 0.14.0)
- *libgranite3* (>= 0.3.1+r930+pkg83~daily~ubuntu0.4.1)

All others necessary libraries are already in Freya. These changes are needed to the latest version of **pantheon-mail** *(pantheon-mail - 1.0.0+r2030+pkg7~daily~ubuntu0.4.1)*

You must keep in mind that **pantheon-mail**, and **libgranite** for Loki 0.4, are under development. So you can find some aditional issues.

More info : [Mail in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-mail)

PPA DAILY VERSION

Also you can get **pantheon-mail** running on Freya (aka **Mail**) from the daily elementary OS PPA. Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-mail
```

Before running, you must remove **Geary** from your system:

```
sudo apt-get remove geary
```

Finally, remove daily ppa to prevent your system become unstable:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

> *P.S.- It is important that during this process not perform a system upgrade or dist-upgrade*

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon. That did get me past the Granite error a bit further to [ 88%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/pantheon-mail.dir/client/conversation-viewer/ConversationWidget.c.o
then it fails again with: make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pantheon-mail.dir/client/conversation-viewer/ConversationWidget.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pantheon-mail.dir/all] Error 2

Comment: @Seth, i've updated my answer. Please, share your results. Cheers.

Comment: Build is still failing at 88%, here's the [bug report with debug build log](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1562951/comments/7)

Comment: Versions of installed dependencies: ```libcairo2-dev                              1.14.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1``` ```libgee-0.8-dev                             0.10.5-1ubuntu1``` ```libgranite-dev                             0.3.1+r871+pkg84~ubuntu0.3.1```

Comment: You can install also via daily ppa to resolve dependencies.

Comment: I was able to install via the daily ppa, thanks for adding that method. Mail still crashes like crazy, as geary did, but at least I can test the latest versions now.

Comment: Easy way to install dependencies when building an app `sudo apt-get build-dep <app-source-code-folder>`